# Create a Datatabase link to Google BigQuery in Oracle fails with an ORA-28511

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery, odbc

I want to connect my Oracle database (11.2) with a BigQuery table with the Database Gateway for ODBC. The ODBC driver (Test after the configuration is successful) is configured as in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/bigquery-from-excel):

**initdg4odbc.ora**:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = "Google BigQuery"
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = 4
```

Following entry was added to the **listener.ora**:

```
(SID_DESC=
  (SID_NAME=DG4ODBC)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
```

And to the tnsnames.ora:

```
BIGQUERY =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=tcp)
      (HOST=localhost)
      (PORT=1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SID=DG4ODBC))
      (HS=OK)
    )
```

So far it looks good and I can do successful tnsping:

```
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=tcp) (HOST=localhost) (PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SID=DG4ODBC)) (HS=OK))
OK (10 msec)
```

Afterwards I have created a database link on the Oracle DB:

CREATE DATABASE LINK google USING 'BIGQUERY';

But once I query the table (the query in Bigquery works find and name is in upper case) via sqlPlus I get the following error message:

```
SQL> select * from TABLE@bigquery;
select * from TABLE@bigquery

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28511: lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using
SID=ORA-28511: lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using
SID=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DAT
A=(SID=DG4ODBC)))
ORA-02063: preceding line from BIGQUERY
Process ID: 16180
Session ID: 49 Serial number: 51
```

Any ideas why the error occurs or where I can find more details for it?

Answer (score 0):

Your tutorial is inconsistent.  At one point he has you create a DSN named "BigQuery", but then has you set credentials for a DSN named "Google BigQuery".  Pick a DSN and stick with it. And this carries back HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO in your init. ora file.

Also, I'd not name the gateway SID as 'DG4ODBC'.  It will work, but is a very mis-leading name.  What will you name the next one you have to create?  I'd name the SID the same as the target database - BigQuery in this case.

You might find this link to be more helpful .. https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/